# XDebug to evaluate when a Variable is set to True from 'else If' Statement

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm in conjunction with a WAMP localhost and have xdebug enabled.

Looking for the best solution to utilize xdebug and PhpStorm in order to debug my PHP script to see which line `$var = true;`

Here's how my script looks. It's a nested `foreach` `for loop`

```
foreach ($array as $index => $values) {

  $count = count($values);

        for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

        $word = false;
        $string = $values[$i]['word'];

               if (isset($values[$i+1]['word'])) { 
        $stringafter = $values[$i+1]['text'];
                                                  }

              if (strpos($string, 'Which') !== false && $word != true) {

                   if (strpos($stringafter, 'of') !== false) {

                       $string = $string;
                       $word = true;
                                                              }

                    else {

                       $string = NULL;
                       $word = true;

                          }

                                                                        }
                                         //ending first if condition loop

               elseif (preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $string) && $word != true) {
               //word contains at least one uppercase letter

                   $uc = preg_match('/^[A-Z]:\.*/', $string, $uccheck);
                   $firstletter = $uccheck[0];

                   if ($firstletter  == strtoupper($firstlette))  {
                       // first letter is uppercase        
                       $string = $string;
                       $word = true;

                                                                   }

                    else {
                        $string = NULL;
                        $word = true;
                         }

                                                                    }
                                 //ending first elseif condition loop

                elseif ($word != true) {

                         $string = NULL;
                         $word = true;

                                       }
   //ending second elseif condition loop


$word = false;
// setting $word back to false at end of for loop for next word

}
//ending for loop

}
//ending foreach loop
```

Currently I'm just putting this breakpoint right above `$searchword = false;`

```
        if ('test' == 'test') {
            $true = true;
            $getword = $word;
        }
```

And then I'm able to iterate through each loop and condition and it will tell me one by one if it goes through this loop and where `$word = true`; is occurring.

This is helpful but seems needlessly slow if all I'm looking to do is find out where in the conditional loops `$word = true;` is occurring for each of my `$string` variables in the `for loop`.

I was hoping I could just right click on the debugger > variables console in PhpStorm where it says `$word = true;` and choosing the option `'Jump to Source'`.. but instead it just brings me back to the beginning of my for loop where `$word = false` is declared.

Is there an easier way besides iterating or reviewing the output to automatically tell me where `$word = true;` is being defined on, instead of manually looking at the debug output?

Edit:

Comments were getting a bit long so I thought I'd reiterate.

@MrGlass helped by explaining that condition statements such as `($word == true)` can be utilized in `if` statements, but upon further testing this condition only works on `if` statements and not `elseif` statements.

Example:

```
Line 100:   elseif (preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $string) && $word != true) {
Line 101:      //word contains at least one uppercase letter
Line 102:          $uc = preg_match('/^[A-Z]:\.*/', $string, $uccheck);
Line 103:          $firstletter = $uccheck[0];
Line 104:   if ($firstletter  == strtoupper($firstlette))  {
Line 105:      // first letter is uppercase        
Line 106:          $string = $string;
Line 107:          $word = true;
Line 108:    }
Line 109:    }
```

As quaintly explained in my comments below if I attach a condition in PHPStorm such as `$word == true` or `($word == true)` to `Line 100`, I get no results/breakpoints. If I attach it to the ending curly braces on `Line 108` or `Line 109`, I still get no matches to my breakpoints.

If I put my breakpoint on Line 104 with the condition `($word == true)` I get the results I Want.

Is there anyway to get xDebug to track this condition in `elseif` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PhpStorm, if you `right-click` on the debug indicator (a circle in the margin by the line number) you can set the condition for the debugger to break on that line.

Comment: Can you provide an example? If I create a line like this: `if ($string == 'North') {` preceded by additional lines `$string = $string;` then `$word = $word;` then `}` If I put the condition for the line `if ($string == 'North') {` as `$word = true` it does not work... it breaks on this line every iteration of my for loop (I suppose showing that it's an if statement so that variable tried to pass it.... but it shouldn't right? My condition condition on this if statement line -- `$word = true` --- does not seem to be taking affect.  Am I doing something wrong to set this condition or what?

Comment: @bbruman, you would enter `($string == 'North')` in the condition field in you wanted it to break on that line when `$string` equals `'North'`. No need to enter a full conditional statement. Just `($string == 'North')`.

Comment: But I want it to break on where `$word = true` not some possible conditional statement where the `$string` loops through.  `$string == 'North'` was only an example (perhaps a bad one as it is so defined), but how do I add the condition to break where `$word = true;` is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @bbruman, you can set the condition to `($word == true)` on any line that you like (and on as many lines as you like).

Comment: I don't think it's working because the breakpoint on the if statement `$word != true` yet---- I'm just trying to determine what if condition loop CONTAINS `$word == true` within it -- not at the start of the if statement where I'm putting the condition ---... this seems to be where things are not going their intended ways... Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: So I can set my breakpoint on the `$word = true` line's on my script, but I still don't get how to add a condition for it. It doesn't seem to attach to an `if` or (mostly tested so far) `elseif` statements very well. I've tried adding the condition at the beginning of the `elseif` statement and at the closing `}`. In fact, my Xdebug competely ignores if I put a breakpoint on an elseif statement. I know I have variables going through it or observing it, but I get no output.

Comment: @bbruman, please usnderstand that using `($word = true)` is not the same as `($word == true)`. The first one sets `$word = true` and the second checks if `$word` is equal to `true`. You need to set the condition of the break point to check `($word == true)`

Comment: Yes I understand. Please review my edits to see what I Attempted. It seems xdebug works with the `($word == true)` for if conditions but not `elseif` conditions (even if the variables passes the `elseif` condition).. as my script entails finding a variable and setting it to true nested elseif conditions are necessary as there should only be one `($word == true)` result for the main part of the loop. Is there any workaround for `elseif` statements? Not even sure why they don't work (and yet `if` statements WITHIN `elseif` statements work)